# Running nitro enclaves and on Amazon EKS and getting Insufficient hugepages-2Mi on pods

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubectl, huge-pages, enclave

I am following [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/enclaves/latest/user/kubernetes.html) to use Nitro Enclaves on EKS. My pods giving me a warning and are stuck in a pending state.

```
0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient aws.ec2.nitro/nitro_enclaves, 2 
Insufficient hugepages-2Mi. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 
2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
```

On checking the nodes I see the following:

```
kubectl describe node ip-x.us-east-2.compute.internal | grep -A 8 "Allocated resources:"
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                325m (4%)   0 (0%)
  memory             140Mi (0%)  340Mi (2%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)

kubectl describe node ip-x.us-east-2.compute.internal | grep -A 13 "Capacity:"                                                                                                                                                                                          
Capacity:
  cpu:                8
  ephemeral-storage:  83873772Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             15896064Ki
  pods:               29
Allocatable:
  cpu:                7910m
  ephemeral-storage:  76224326324
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             14879232Ki
  pods:               29
```

Pod Definition Include:

```
"containers": [
      {
        "name": "hello-container",
        "image": "hello-f9c725ee-4d02-4f48-8c3f-f341a754061b:latest",
        "command": [
          "/home/run.sh"
        ],
        "resources": {
          "limits": {
            "aws.ec2.nitro/nitro_enclaves": "1",
            "cpu": "250m",
            "hugepages-2Mi": "100Mi"
          },
          "requests": {
            "aws.ec2.nitro/nitro_enclaves": "1",
            "cpu": "250m",
            "hugepages-2Mi": "100Mi"
          }
        },
```

Things that I have tried:
Tried vertical and horizontal scaling and also restarting the Kubelet service after reading a couple of other articles, but with no success, and pods are still stuck in a pending state.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be two potential problems here, one related to the lack of `hugepages-2Mi`, and one related to the lack of `aws.ec2.nitro/nitro_enclaves`.  I'll be referencing https://docs.aws.amazon.com/enclaves/latest/user/kubernetes.html during this.

For `hugepages-2Mi`, make sure that the launch template created in Step 1 is actually applied to the nodes in your nitro-providing EKS node group, and that the `user data` is correctly set on that launch template.  Note that if you modified the `user data` to supply a # of MB that is a multiple of 1024, instead of `hugepages-2Mi`, you'll get `hugepages-1Gi`, as described in step 5.1 under `limits`.

For `aws.ec2.nitro/nitro_enclaves`, you need to make sure that an pod of the DaemonSet provided at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-nitro-enclaves-k8s-device-plugin/main/aws-nitro-enclaves-k8s-ds.yaml is running on your nitro-enabled node.  It could be missing because either the DaemonSet was not correctly added to your K8S, or because the node label for your nitro-enabled nodes are incorrect (they should be `aws-nitro-enclaves-k8s-dp=enabled`, which should be visible in `kubectl describe node`).  If the DaemonSet pod is in fact up and running, it also may have issues.  You can check with `kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l name=aws-nitro-enclaves-k8s-dp --tail=1000`